# How to reinstall the test application removed from the iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, testing

Yesterday I installed test application from Xcode on iPhone, but I deleted it after work. Today I want to test it again, but I cannot run it, because I get an error:

```
Details

Unable to launch com.myname.myapp
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: -12
--
Request to launch com.myname.myapp failed.
Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice
Code: 2
Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.myname.myapp" is unknown to FrontBoard. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.myname.myapp'.
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.myname.myapp" is unknown to FrontBoard.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain
Code: 4
Failure Reason: Application "com.myname.myapp" is unknown to FrontBoard.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = NotFound;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4.1 (16137)
```

Is it any way to reinstall app on my device?

Comment: Use React? I see some other cases where that's involved.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'use react'?

Comment: OK, if it doesn't it doesn't. Just asking.

Answer (score -2):

**You can try one of the following**

1. You can try re-installing Xcode
2. Duplicate the app
3. Change the bundle ID to another app's Bundle ID you have installed on your iPhone.
4. Try on a different mac
5. Test on another iPhone
6. Use the simulator
7. If it still doesn't work, contact Apple or comment
8. You probably changed your bundle ID